# Why is the column called "Soft Credit For" when it seems to show "Soft Credit from"?

Tags: search-results, soft-credit

Helen made the contribution with soft credit to Priya so why is the column called **Soft credit For** rather than **Soft Credit From**?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Good question. There is probably no explanation except that the developer who implemented it called it this way. Maybe by mistake.

If you feel this is wrong you can file an issue and if you have technical expertise you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

CiviCRM's soft crediting allows users to assign soft credit types to contributions. Assigning an appropriate reserved or custom soft credit type enables administrators to properly attribute contributions received through one or more charitable contribution types (such as Donor Advised Funds, Scholarships, Family Bequests, etc) whether solicited (P2P) or not.

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/soft-credits/